# Unable to install flash plugin due to a proxy

Tags: flash

Yesterday I upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit). The upgrade went smoothly (far more than I expected). Unfortunately, I cannot seem to install the flash plugin in either Firefox or Chrome.

```
chrome://plugins
```

does not show flash. I tried

```
19:17farhat ~$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
flashplugin-installer is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Yet, I cannot seem to find anything related to flash on the system.

```
19:17farhat ~$ sudo updatedb
[sudo] password for farhat: 
19:17farhat ~$ locate libflashplayer.so
19:17farhat ~$ locate libflashplayer
19:17farhat ~$ locate libflash
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libflashlo.so
19:17farhat ~$
```

I am at the end of everything I know. Any help will be appreciated. I have tried removing and reinstalling the package. Still the same results.

Comment: It's connected with launchpad bug [1052377](http://bugs.launchpad.net/update-notifier/+bug/1052377) bug, please vote "this bug affects me to"

Comment: have a look at this answer, it worked for me

http://askubuntu.com/a/178569/26067

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the solution was provided by Farhat in a comment. Here is a step-by-step instruction.

1. `sudo su`
2. `export http_proxy="http://address.to.my.proxy/"`
3. `apt-get remove flashplugin-installer`
4. `apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Comment: A more elegant way to get a `root` shell, using just `sudo`, is `sudo -s`.

Answer (score 3):

Open terminal via Dash (Dash then type in Terminal, click on it). Then type in the following two commands:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/google/chrome/plugins
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so /opt/google/chrome/plugins
```

Restart chrome

When sudo prompts for your password, type it in, it won't show up, so remember what you type in.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome uses its own built-in version of Flash, so I have no idea why it doesn't work. As for the other programs, try reinstalling `flashplugin-installer`.

- `sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer`
- `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Perhaps the update broke or removed some files.

Comment: It was an issue with proxy settings not getting transferred under sudo. It worked after I used a root shell with 'export http_proxy=...'. I feel if the install does not complete due to such a reason apt-get should not say the package has been installed and refuse to reinstall it.

Comment: It's advisable to run `sudo apt-get update` before (re)installing packages from the command line (this updates the local database of what software is available, in what versions and from where). Also, you can reinstall software with one package management step using `sudo apt-get --reinstall install flashplugin-installer`. You can reinstall it, removing all configuration files during the removal process, using `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install flashplugin-installer`.

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox, there is a plugin that works wonders; I found out about it from the Reddit Ubuntu forum, and I believe it was written by a Redditor.  [flash-aid](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-aid/).

Comment: removed by it's author

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the package called ubuntu-restricted-extras? You can do this in the Software Center or, if you prefer the to use the command-line, then by running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```