# 12.04 LTS flashplugin-installer problem

Tags: 12.04, flash

When I install flashplugin i have problem :

```
flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.235.orig.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 234, in process_download_requests
    dest_file = urllib.urlretrieve(files[i])[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 93, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 239, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 207, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 344, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 757, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 113] No route to host
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 234, in process_download_requests
    dest_file = urllib.urlretrieve(files[i])[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 93, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 239, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 207, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 344, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 757, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 113] No route to host
Konfigurowanie flashplugin-installer (11.2.202.235ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
```

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: By below comments and answers this obviously is a bug. Report here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/982684

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem with the installation of `flashplugin-installer` in Ubuntu 12.04.  I have fixed this bug by:

1. Adding the correct proxy in  `/etc/environment`  and `/etc/wgetrc`
2. Adding the following  line in `/etc/sudoers`:

   - `Defaults env_keep="http_proxy"`
3. By installing the following:

   - `sudo  apt-get install policykit-1`
   - `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`
   - `sudo apt-get --reinstall install flashplugin-installer`

And now the problem is solved.

Comment: great, that was really hard to figure our without your help

Comment: works for Ubuntu 14.04 as well.

Answer (score 3):

"No route to host" is a network connectivity problem.

Do you have an otherwise working internet connection?

You may want to check:

- Can you ping either host (`archive.canonical.com` or `downloads.sourceforge.net`) from the same PC?
- Do you have any firewall or other network setup that could be blocking access to these sites?
- Do you rely on a proxy server to access the web that you may have configured in your browser and in APT, but that Python/update-notifier is not picking up?  If so, [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/982684) may be helpful in 12.04.  Essentially the problem is that the installer for these two packages require access to the web to download data, but sudo is not passing them your system proxy settings (APT gets it proxy settings a different way so is unaffected).

Comment: I haven't any internet connection problems. I use proxy and everthing working properly.

Comment: Then my third dot point is relevant to you.  Python is not picking up your proxy settings.  The installer for these two packages (flashplugin-installer and ttf-mscorefonts-installer) need to download files from web sites in order to install.  They do this with Python scripts.

Comment: This bug report may be helpful or relevant here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/982684 - essentially the problem is that the installer for these two packages flashplugin-installer and ttf-mscorefonts-installer require access to the web, but sudo is unable to pass them proxy settings (APT gets it proxy settings a different way so is unaffected).

Comment: Just to add to this answer. The workaround from the bug report is to use "sudo -i apt-get install" to install this package until the bug is fixed.