# Install MS fonts without using ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Tags: 12.04, fonts

Is it possible to install the MS fonts without using the ttf-mscorefonts-installer, and if so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer).

Comment: @karel It's not a duplicate. I know how to accept the Microsoft EULA agreement using the tab key.

Comment: @karel Am getting this error http://askubuntu.com/questions/140558/12-04-lts-flashplugin-installer-problem and I don't know how to solve it coz am not using a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the actual `ttf`-font files, you can copy them to `~/.fonts/` (or if you want them system-wide, to `/usr/share/fonts/`).